# How many CALs are installed on my server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, cal, cals

How can I find out what sort of Client Access Licenses and how many of them are installed on this Server 2008 system I have been asked to administer?

Answer (score 4):

In Windows 2008 you don't actually enter the CALs into the OS.  You'll need to check the purchase history to see how many you have purchased.

Comment: So is it basically just on the honor system then?

Comment: Yep. But if you don't have enough and Microsoft comes and audit's you the fines are VERY expensive and you run the risk of having them revoke your license to use their software.